# Dealing with the Huntress as a survivor

Tags: dead-by-daylight

As a survivor, I'm still learning how to play against the Huntress.  I'm often getting wounded by the throwing hatchets despite trying to dodge in and out of cover.  Generators closer to the center of the map or in the middle of farm crops seem too risky to repair with her mobility and range.

**How can I more effectively survive and escape against the Huntress?**

Answer (score 4):

### Hiding

While the Huntress can hit you from farther away than other killers by throwing axes, you can also hear her coming from a greater distance. Use this to your advantage by getting ready to evade her or hiding earlier. Try to avoid hiding in sheds as the Huntress is more likely to open them to replenish her axes. Instead, you should try to walk or crouch-walk away from her and keep objects in between you so she can't spot you.

Try to have an escape plan ready to go wherever you are so that if she approaches your position, you'll already be gone. If you're interacting with something (generators, chests, etc.) try to scan the distance when possible, if you see the Huntress heading your way it may be a good idea to get ready to hide. Remember that if she never sees you, she won't hit you.

### Avoiding

If she spots you, try to break the line of sight as quickly as possible and then get away from her or hide. Avoid running unless you're certain she knows exactly where you are, as the trail you leave will make it very easy for her to find you. Sprint burst and light weight are useful perks to take if you find the Huntress catches you often, they will let you get further away and make you harder to follow if you need to run. Try to avoid open areas and head for buildings or walls that you can then sneak around in, but tall grass or cornfields will also do as long as she isn't immediately behind you. It can be surprisingly hard to follow a survivor through grass if you aren't right on top of them, remember that the killer has a much narrower field of view than you.

### Surviving a Chase

If you are in a chase with the Huntress, be careful about using windows and pallets as these are the best times for her to throw an axe at you. Whenever she winds up to throw, she'll stop humming (and I think she makes a grunting noise?). If you hear this, anticipate when you think she's going to have a good shot and make a sharp turn away from that direction, or run past her if she's really close to you. Most Huntress players will be expecting you to do this, and will often figure out how you dodge after a couple of tries or will just hit you despite your efforts, so it's in your best interest to get away quickly. After the Huntress throws an axe is the best time to hop over a window or put a pallet in her way, since she won't be able to throw a second one right away.

If you manage to get away from the Huntress but have been hit, try to get as far away from her as you can without being noticed since she may hear you or spot your blood if she's close. When I play Huntress, I find that I get most of my kills by listening for survivors that I've wounded with an axe, many seem to think that I won't hear them. Taking the self-healing perk, using a med-kit, or getting another survivor to heal you will improve this, but these are noisy or easy to spot if you're still close to her.

Comment: If you're ever caught in the open and hear her winding up a hatchet, don't run in a straight line, this makes it very easy for her to hit a hatchet. Shake your character left and right so she doesn't know which way you're going to go. Once you hear her throw a hatchet commit to either side. More times than not this will let you dodge the hatchet.